# What's the difference between the "serialize" and "rustc-serialize" crates?

Tags: rust

This is the [`serialize` crate](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/index.html), and this is the [`rustc-serialize` crate](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc-serialize/index.html).

I'm getting deprecation warnings from the compiler when using the `Encodable` and `Decodable` traits from the `serialize` crate. The compiler tells me to use `RustcEncodable` and `RustcDecodable` from the `rustc-serialize` crate.

It seems like this just makes things less readable for the same functionality (apart from `base64` encoding provided in `rustc-serialize`). What's the difference between these crates?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `serialize` crate is an *internal* part of the standard Rust distribution. It won't be available in the Rust 1.0 stable/beta channels.

The `rustc-serialize` crate used to be `serialize`, but it was moved out to a separate repository and uploaded to crates.io so that it can evolve on its own.

This was done because the utility of `rustc-serialize` is enormous but it was not realistic to get it stabilized in time for Rust 1.0. Since the Rust distribution will prohibit unstable features on the stable channel, the only way to continue using the serialization infrastructure is to 1) stabilize what we have or 2) move it to crates.io, where the unstable restrictions don't apply.

`rustc-serialize` has a lot of known downsides, and [it is being worked on](https://github.com/erickt/rust-serde), so stabilizing what was there really isn't an option.

But the `Decodable/Encodable` features require compiler support (because compiler plugins won't be stable either for Rust 1.0). As a stopgap measure, `RustcDecodable/RustcEncodable` were invented as a temporary measure for the `rustc-serialize` crate to use explicitly. It's a bit weird, but it leaves the `Decodable/Encodable` names available for a future backwards-compatible version of a `serialize` crate that is better than what we have now (perhaps this is what `serde2` will become from the aforementioned link).

So for the time being, stick to use `rustc-serialize` and `RustcDecodable/RustcEncodable`.

(I apologize that I can't come up with a link to cite all of this. It's knowledge I've accrued over time from GitHub issues. Maybe there is an RFC that lays all of this out though. I can't remember.)

Comment: Note that `serialize` has been deprecated in favor of `rustc-serialize` which in turn has been deprecated in favor of `serde` as per the official document.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [BurntSushi5's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28457675/155423), as of the time of this writing, the Rust compiler in both Stable and Beta channels throws the following error when attempting to use vanilla `serialize`:

```
error: use of unstable library feature 'rustc_private': deprecated in favor of rustc-serialize on crates.io (see issue #27812)
 --> src/main.rs:2:1
  |
2 | extern crate serialize;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The [linked Github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27812) is not very helpful. In short, use `rustc-serialize`.